# Records updating based on primary key is slow

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, informatica

I'm updating 60k records in 200k records using informatica based only only one primary key. Still it is running longer. Is there a way to reduce the time as we cannot create index on primary key again which is not necessary.

Comment: Can you post your table structure, what you are updating, how you are updating, your sql statements.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot create index on primary key again' ? The primary key constraint will be implemented via a unique index by Oracle even if you didn't specify one.

Comment: For update indexing wil consume time and unique index is also there right . hence why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for this is deleting and inserting which is a faster alternative way and it works.

Answer (score 0):

60k updated rows out of 200k total is a pretty high hit rate. An indexed read would be extremely inefficient compared to a Full Table Scan. So really you don't want to use the primary key index to do an update like this.

However it's difficult to provide more assistance unless you can post the exact query that's being executed, preferably with its explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your target table has multiple indexes defined on it (regardless of how many keys you are using to do the update) also there might be multiple foreign keys which need to be resolved against their related tables. Ignore informatica for a minute and try run the update directly on the db and resolve